# How do I override input[type="text"] for Html.TextBoxFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to set the width of one particular textbox in my view. No matter what I've tried, the following code in Site.css takes precedence:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
{
  // other properties
  width: 200px;
}
```

I have tried:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Headline, new { style = "width: 400" })
```

and

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Headline, new { @class = "wide" })
```

and

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Headline, new { @id = "headline" })
```

But the only thing that matters is the input[type="text"] width. I don't want to change *all* the inputs, just this one.

I did set the width in my .css file for .wide and #headline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use then input[name="name"] or an id for an example? And if you want to make one style more important than another one use !important at the end of the css-attribute. Like:

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 200px;
}
input[name="foo"] {
    width: 500px !important;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion, and everything I tried before, does work, if I put it *after* the default 'input' setting in my CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Go with

```
.wide {
    width: 500px !important;
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Headline, new { class = "wide" })
```

or

```
#wideBox {
    width: 500px;
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Headline, new { id = "wideBox" })
```